# ASP. NET MVC 5: If user is admin, return the list of all the users

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have created both the login and registration page in ***ASP.NET MVC 5***. There is a role option on the registration page that asks whether the user is an **admin** or a **non-admin**.

Now if the user that is trying to log in is an **admin** then I have to **display all the users** present in the database but if the user is a **non-admin** then I have to display **"Hi! Name of the User"** on the page.

I'm attaching the code of my **AccountController** below.

```cs
using MyFirstApp.DBModel;
using MyFirstApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyFirstApp.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        DEV_Training_DemoEntities objDEV_Training_DemoEntities = new DEV_Training_DemoEntities();
        // GET: Account 
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            UserModel objUserModel = new UserModel();
            return View(objUserModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(UserModel objUserModel)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (!objDEV_Training_DemoEntities.AN_Users.Any(m => m.Username == objUserModel.Username))
                { 
                    AN_Users objUser = new AN_Users();
                    objUser.Name = objUserModel.Name;
                    objUser.DOB = objUserModel.DOB;
                    objUser.Username = objUserModel.Username;
                    objUser.Password = objUserModel.Password;
                    objUser.Gender = objUserModel.Gender;
                    objUser.Role = objUserModel.Role;
                    objDEV_Training_DemoEntities.AN_Users.Add(objUser);
                    objDEV_Training_DemoEntities.SaveChanges();
                    objUserModel.SucessMessage = "You are successfully registered!";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Username already exists!");
                    return View();
                }
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            LoginModel objLoginModel = new LoginModel();
            return View(objLoginModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel objLoginModel)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (objDEV_Training_DemoEntities.AN_Users.Where(m => m.Username == objLoginModel.Username && m.Password == objLoginModel.Password).FirstOrDefault() == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Invalid Email-ID or Password!");
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    var curruser = objDEV_Training_DemoEntities.AN_Users.Where(m => m.Username == objLoginModel.Username && m.Password == objLoginModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                    if(curruser.Role)
                    Session["Username"] = objLoginModel.Username;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Can you show the error please?

Comment: No error is there, I just don't know how to execute this.

Comment: @Abhishek Negi, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make an if statement if user==admin then foreach var user in userlist cw(username)
else cw(username)

Comment: I know this but I don't know how to code this as this is my first project. So can you help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method to return the list of users when the user is admin.

cshtml:

```
@using WebApplication2.Models
@model Users
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";

}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <span>Enter Your Name:</span> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    <br />
    <span>Enter Your Age: </span> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.role,
new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Role))),
"Select Role")
    <br />

    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />

    <hr />

    <strong>UserName: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)
    <br />
    <strong>Role: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.role)
    <br />

    <b style="color:red">Userlist: @ViewBag.Message</b>

}
```

Users:

```
 public class Users
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Role role { get; set; }
    }



    public enum Role
    { 
        Admin=1,
        NonAdmin=2
    
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {


        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Users um)
        {
            if(um.role==Role.Admin)
            {
                var list = GetUserlist();
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message += item.Name + " | ";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string str = string.Format("Hi! {0} of the User",um.Name);
                Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + str + "');</script>");


            }
            return View(um);
        }


        public List<Users> GetUserlist()
        {
            List<Users> users = new List<Users>();
           // here is you get data from database
            return users;

        }

    }
```

Result:

[image]